# Bootstrap SImple Sidebar - Content below overlaps

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

I'm using the Sidebar Template (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/) and i want some content below the sidebar and the content to the right of the sidebar. It works fine, but when i resize the window the content below overlaps and goes all the way to the top.

I got something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                    Start Bootstrap
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
                    <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                    <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>

<!-- /#wrapper -->
<div id="content-below">

</div>
```

Where should i place the "content-below" container to prevent it from going all the way to the top after resizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just comment out the following section in css:

```
#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    /* position: absolute; */
    padding: 15px;
}
```

see example here [codepen](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/NAJwAz?editors=0110)

enjoy.. :)